# Actual Difference between Reference and Object

Tags: c#

There is a Statement that:

> Methods are called by objects and not by reference.

But I don't understand, what is the Difference between reference and Object.

Consider the Example:

```
Animal a=new Animal();
```

**(or)**

```
Base b=new Derived();
```

Comment: You may find this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the statement a translation?

Comment: Are you talking about how parameters are passed into methods? If yes, I do not get how your example refers to that. Please be more specific.

Comment: the quote and the examples don't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

I can explain like below

This is an object

```
public class Person
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public String SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

You cannot access directly Name, Surname and SayHello from Object like below,

```
Person.Name = "Onur";
Person.Surname = "Tekir";
Person.SayHello();
```

You should create instanca of an object. This instance is a reference of object

```
Person person = new Person();
```

Now, you can access properties and methods of reference of Person object,

```
person.Name = "Onur";
person.Surname = "Tekir";
person.SayHello();
```